# Python Ethereum Blockchain Transactions

Tags: python, python-3.x, ethereum, web3py, go-ethereum

I want to get ethereum block-chain transactions using python. I've imported the following libraries:

```
import psycopg2
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
import sys
import pprint
```

When I run the`.py` file with python command with sudo like **`sudo python file.py`**, I get the following error:

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider 
ImportError: No module named web3
```

And when i run the same python file with python3 with sudo like **`sudo python3 file.py`**, I get the following error:

```
import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

**Operating System:** Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS bionic

**python -V :** Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

**python3 -V :** Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

I have tried lot of commands to install web3 and psycopg2 but all vain.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use such libraries you have to install them.

You can do that by using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/):

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install psycopg2
```

Some additional actions could be necessary based on which library you are trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues as well with the web3 installation. After hours of searching for an answer, downloading the "Visual Studio Build Tools 2019" and running my venv again after that, finally solved my problem. Hope this can help out.

I also installed Cython for python

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Anaconda installs its own version of Python in a location that is different from the location installed on your system.

Try executing the `pip install <module_name>` commands in Anaconda shell ( and not the unix shell )

One way to identify that it is an Anaconda shell, is that it will would have created a virtual environment and enabled it in the shell window for you.